# Given a list of list of Booleans, return a Boolean

Tags: haskell

I have a function, defined as follows, that is given a list of lists of Booleans and returns a Boolean:

```
evaluates :: [[Bool]] -> Bool
```

I tried the following way:

```
evaluates  :: [[Bool]] -> Bool
evaluates  ((y:ys):xs) = (y && (head ys)) || evaluates (tail xs)
```

but this doesn't work.

The result I expect is:

```
[True && False && True] ||  [True] || [False && False]] = True
```

For an entry of: `[[True, False, True], [True], [False, False]]`

Comment: Consider your base cases, and write down what `evaluates` should output for the following inputs: `[]`, `[] : xs`, `(y:ys) : xs`.  Your current implementation only considers one of these cases, and depends on `ys` matching `_ : _`, as `head` is not defined on `[]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You try to do *too* much in a single function. Let us solve the problem in three steps:

1. create a function that takes a list of `Bool`s, and returns the logical AND of these `Bool`s;
2. create a function that takes a list of `Bool`s and returns the logical OR of these `Bool`s; and
3. create a function that takes a list of `[Bool]`s, first maps it with the first function, and then performs the second function on that.

We can implement the first function with a [**`foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr):

```
_and :: [Bool] -> Bool
_and = foldr (&&) True
```

in fact, the Haskell prelude already *has* an [**`and :: Foldable f => f Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:and) function.

The second function can be implemented with a `foldr` as well:

```
_or :: [Bool] -> Bool
_or = foldr (||) False
```

The Haskell prelude already *has* an [**`or :: Foldable f => f Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:or) function.

Now we can define `evaluate` with [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
evaluate :: [[Bool]] -> Bool
evaluate = _or . map _and
```

We can even generalize the above to work with two (possibly different) `Foldable`s:

```
evaluate :: (Foldable f, Foldable g) => f (g Bool) -> Bool
evaluate = foldr ((||) . and) False
```

or like [@DanielWagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517712/given-a-list-of-list-of-booleans-return-a-boolean/56517783?noredirect=1#comment99640180_56517783) says, we can use [**`any :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any):

```
evaluate :: (Foldable f, Foldable g) => f (g Bool) -> Bool
evaluate = any and
```

For example:

```
Prelude> evaluate [[True, False, True], [True], [False, False]]
True
Prelude> evaluate [Just False, Just False, Nothing]
True
Prelude> evaluate [Just False, Just False, Just False]
False
Prelude> evaluate (Just [True, False, True])
False
Prelude> evaluate (Just [True, True, True])
True
```

Comment: `evaluate = any and`?

Comment: @DanielWagner: yes, somehow I did not think about that :s.